# android View Pager with Dates as Title

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I want to display a View Pager with Date, Week and Month as Title. 
So i have spinner in the Toolbar with the value(Daily, weekly & Monthly)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar                       
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/bg_image"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_top_padding"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Based upon the selection the Fragments change.

```
spinner_nav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
     int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    switch(position){
    case 0:
        CommonUtilities.replaceFragment(new WeeklyFragment(), getSupportFragmentManager());
        break;
    case 1:
        CommonUtilities.replaceFragment(new DailyFragment(), getSupportFragmentManager());
        break;
    case 2:
        CommonUtilities.replaceFragment(new MonthlyFragment(), getSupportFragmentManager());
        break;
    }
```

For endless page swiping, i used this code from [Viewpager in Android to switch between days endlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584129/viewpager-in-android-to-switch-between-days-endlessly/23410686#23410686).

Problem: I cant able to set page title and Page Select Indicator. How to do this. To achieve this , There is any library available or can help me with this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this library: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator or simply use PagerTitleStrip (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html)